# Asp.net: save data entry form with PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods

The problem: I have a data entry form. I would like to save the data without page roundtrip or UpdatePanels.

The solution: 
- the 'Save' button calls a javascript function which serialize all the fields content (client side)
- the javascript function calls a web method (server side)
- the web method deserialize the data and save it to the database.

Am I doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: yes

---

In more than a word: yes you are doing it one way which is a good implementation.

Points to think about are security of the service (if on a public site), serialisation of the data methods - json is probably easiest to process both client side and server side.